# Java / JPA - dynamically setting properties on an object / entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm relatively new to Java and would appreciate any help on this!

I have an XML file full of products like this:

```
<product>
    <title>Product Title</title>
    <colour>Red</colour>
</product>
```

And I have a JPA Entity like this:

```
@Entity
public Product extends Model {

    public String title;
    public String colour;

}
```

And I can happily parse the XML into my JPA object like this:

```
public void parseElement(String elementName, String elementValue) {
    if (elementName == "title") {
        product.title = elementValue;
    }
    else if (elementName == "colour") {
        product.colour = elementValue;
    }
}
```

**However** the problem is that there are over 50 fields per product, not just the two. I could write a 50+ clause if-else statement, but thought it'd be worth checking here for better alternatives first!

As the XML element names directly match to the property names in the Product class, I thought something like this would be perfect:

```
public void parseElement(String elementName, String elementValue) {
    product[elementName] = elementValue;
}
```

But Java doesn't like that notation. Is there something else I can do that would achieve a similar result, or do I have to suck it up and write a collosal if-else statement?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Accepted answer was great solution for problem at the time. Months later a whole bunch of changes were requested that made it worth spending the time trying out the suggested libraries and they were great - thanks for the suggestions. I'm now working on porting over to XStream. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection (error handling ommitted).

```
product.getClass().getDeclaredField(elementName).set(product, elementValue);
```

But I stand by others who have suggested XStream. It's a much cleaner way to parse XML files.

Comment: I take the point of using XStream and will definately look into it but for now, since my XML parsing is "adequate", this has helped me out a great deal thanks. Awarded it as accepted answer as it's generic enough for me to use for other similar problems that don't relate to XML.

Answer (score 5):

Java knows a lot frameworks for XML processing. Also some libs for serializing/deserializing objects to/from xml. I would recommend to have a look at [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Comment: Will definitely look into it, thanks! As I said in another comment though my XML parsing is fit for purpose at the minute (using SAX and a custom handler) so was only looking to add the final tweak (tight deadlines!). Will give JAXB a whirl next time I start fresh, sounds cool :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use something like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to serialize/deserialize your entities to and from xml.

Comment: As with my JAXB comment I don't really have time to re-do all of the parsing (I'm particularly cautious as I'm dealing with JPA entities as well not just standard objects). But I'll definately give XStream a whirl once the workload eases off a bit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout BeanUtils.setProperty

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

Comment: I don't know why but I couldn't get this to work with my current setup (Play! framework, JPA and Hibernate), but thanks anyway. Will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps not the best solution but you could also simply use a map:

```
public Product extends Model { 
  public Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
```

and:

```
public void parseElement(String elementName, String elementValue) {
   product.myMap.put(elementName,elementValue);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too but I don't know how I could get it to play nicely with JPA. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the very well known [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and then do something like this:

```
FieldUtils.writeField(myObject, fieldName, fieldValue);
```